# Trying to make a if statement that will move on after it's done something in bash

Tags: bash, unix, centos

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

So, I am trying to make a script a little bit smart.

I want it to check if a folder exists and if it does just move on but if it does not then it will create a folder for me and then move on to the next part of the script.

The issue is I can get it to make the folder but then the program just dies, I am a little stuck and scratching my head a little.

Now I have a If statement but It will create the folder and then just stop.

```
    TEMPDEST="/home/user/folder"


        if [ ! -d "$TEMPDEST" ]; then
          # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist.
          echo -e "\e[31mOh, I could not find the folder but it's fine I will create one for you now =D!\e[0m"
          mkdir $TEMPDEST
        fi

#Moving into said dirctory to make sure everything is in one folder.
        cd $TEMPDEST

Other stuff....
```

I am using bash on a CentOS machine.

Thanks, 
Callum.

Comment: `$TEMPDEST="/home/user/folder"` should be `TEMPDEST="/home/user/folder"` without the dollar symbol `$`

Comment: That was my mistake its not like that in the script I will change it here.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can use `mkdir -p` for this purpose (although you'll still need your `if` if you still want to print that message).

Comment: What's the other 'stuff' part of the script..how are you verifying nothing is happening after the 'if'?

Comment: By default, bash will just execute the commands in order until there is nothing more to execute.

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic the 'stuff' is just grabbing the files and then tarting them and moving them to another location ready for backing up. This all works and has been teated without the if statement. (The rest of the script is not really relevant to the question).

Comment: @CLGREEN Based on your own answer, the rest of the script is *absolutely* relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little more googling and playing around I found out how to get it to work like I want.

```
if [ ! -d "$TEMPDEST" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist.
  echo -e "\e[31mOh, I could not find the folder but it's fine I will create on for you now =D!\e[0m"
  mkdir $TEMPDEST;
    continue
fi
```

So, I just added 'then continue'.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: it's much more conventional to just run `mkdir -p dirname` unconditionally -- that succeeds if the directory already exists *or* if it's able to create it, so there's no reason to run any test first.

Comment: And btw, consider avoiding `echo -e` -- implementing that option is the single more glaring place where bash breaks the POSIX standard (which doesn't allow `echo` to honor any options other than `-n`). The standardized, preferred replacement is `printf` -- which will work more reliably across multiple shells (and differently-configured versions of bash; bash *can* be configured to have a standards-compliant `echo`, which won't honor `-e`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, While I do agree, I am trying to expand my bash knowledge by playing around. I do understand that it's going around the world and is a complex way of doing it. but I am planning on making something a little more complexity and the checks would be nice. so in this case it would work very well. 

Also Noted I will change the echo now to printf. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `continue` command skips the rest of the current iteration of a surrounding `while` or `for` loop. If that's what you need... there's something going on that isn't al all part of what you've described. It looks to me like there's something wrong with the part of the script that you omitted, and this is somehow working around that problem.